# Reload Listview in vb6

Tags: vba, vb6

I am working on Vb6.
And I have a Listview which displays data from a table, but when i update the database values i want reload the data into listview.
it is get reloaded but previous data is also present with new one.
pls help.

Comment: You have both VBA and VB6 tags and you mention table, are you working within MS Access? Perhaps you could add some detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call

```
 YourListView.ListItems.Clear
```

before you (re)load any data into your listview.